# Rename the folder of wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

i m trying to hide the information that i m using wordpress for my blog so when users see view source code of my blog , they can easily make out by seeing the wp-include,wp-content that they have used wordpress  so how can we hide or rename those folder name 
i made it

```
define ('WP_CONTENT_DIR','/name_of_new_folder');
define('WP_CONTENT_URL','http://example.com/name_of_new_folder');
```

then i  find where ever we have used wp-includes then replaced with includes 
that time it was working but when you try to login from admin panel 
its showing some error called header  already sent  `function_panel`

Comment: Their files are already protected with .htaccess rules, they're safe.. if you alias to them or rename them nothing changes.

Comment: You can't hide information that you're using wordpress, it's always visible and simply changing folder names won't give you what you're looking for. what are you trying to do exactly ?

Comment: thanks for your reply is there any other way to hide the details that i m using  wordpress

Comment: it depends, can you tell me exactly what you're trying to do and why do you want to hide it ?

Comment: Something to read on the topic: http://kovshenin.com/2013/dont-hide-the-fact-that-youre-using-wordpress/

Comment: @Mostafa Torbjørn Berg thanks for your reply and actually i want to hide   http://test.wordpress.com/wp-includes/style.css this i want to change into http://test.wordpress.com/style.css same way for all js and css files

Comment: No you're missing my question, I'm trying to know WHY you want to hide wordpress ? it's not a good idea usually and if you have to hide it for security that usually means you're configuring something completely wrong ! :)

Comment: @mostafa i want do something like this href="http://www.wordpress.com/wp-content/themes/thmename/css/some.css" into  http://www.wordpress.com/css/some.css  
 and  src="http://www.wordpress.com/wp-content/plugins/jquery-updater/js/jquery.js"  into http://www.wordpress.com/jquery-updater/js/jquery.js

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @mostafa i don want that user should know that i m using wordpress

Answer (score 1):

You **should not** edit core files, this will only bring troubles/bugs/headaches. Restore your system from a fresh WordPress copy.

I'm yet to see any technique that allows hiding `wp-admin` and `wp-includes`, seems impossible.

Anyway, carefully editing all necessary options and fine-tuning the theme allows a front-end that doesn't show ***any*** trace of `wp-content`. It's all outlined in this WordPress Answers post: [Steps to Take to Hide the Fact a Site is Using WordPress?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1507/12615).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Better WP Security Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/) it lets you rename your content Directory Name and its free.

You can also suppress header info and generate random version numbers for wordpress and plugins.